# Does this name's pronunciation match the spelling?

Tags: english, orthography, names

I want to use a unique name as my personal, yet it's spelling is very unclear to me. The pronunciation is "E m ai l" As in- E-end, M-me, AI-lie, L-live. Emphasized as word "agile". Is it correct to write it as "Emile"? There are plenty of variations of that name due to it's origins, but this pronunciation has no cultural background as it originated in an accident. Is it allowed to write it as "Emile", or some other spelling is necessary due to rules of English language. Such as Emael, Emeyel, Emil, Emyle etc. Is there any reason why a spelling could be incorrect and is there proof that other is correct? 
Am sorry my English knowledge is rather narrow in these things.

Comment: Are you asking how your name is spelled?

Comment: It is **allowed** to write your name any way you like. But if you want people to pronounce it roughly correctly, then you are more constrained. If I see "Emile", I would think it was French, and pronounce ie /ɛmi:l/. I can't think of a foolproof way of getting /ɛmʌɪl/. "Emyle" might work for some people, but others might think it's just an odd way of spelling the French name. You could try "Emighl" - people would think it odd, but they might get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Brfxxccxxmnpcccclllmmnprxvclmnckssqlbb11116

Don't worry I didn't hit my head into my keyboard! This was a real name given to a child in Sweden it is actually pronounced as "Albin". Having said that you can write your name however you like but if the phonological constraints force people to pronounce it in any other way I must say yes. As we have other words like /dâvid/ or even my name /âdæl/ it's, to some extent, personal (depends on the other people's culture and first language).